# Hipmob with Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Has anyone of you ever used Hipmob to integrate chat capabilities into your Cordova/Phonegap Apps? I am playing with this and I´m just wondering how I could invoke this function with a button. I am building an Cordova/Phonegap App for android platform.

Here is the code I want to invoke using a button:

```
<script>

if( window.plugins && window.plugins.Hipmob ) {
        var hipmob_app_id = '<HIPMOB APPLICATION ID>';
        var Hipmob = window.plugins.Hipmob;

        Hipmob.openChat(hipmob_app_id, {
    'title': 'Help',
    'user': '<hipmob user id>',
    'name': 'Femi',
    'email': 'femi@hipmob.com',
    'context': 'shopping for shoes',
    'location': 'At home'
    });
    } else {
      alert('Hipmob plugin not available/ready.');
    }

</script>
```

Here is a reference of the repository where this is available:

```
https://github.com/Hipmob/cordova-plugin-hipmob-android
```

Thank you... your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, what happened when you ran that code?

Comment: the app does not run at all... and when I check status on the console it says that the hipmob plugin is not ready